# How can I prevent trailing whitespace being trimmed when importing a file into MemoQ 8.4?

Tags: translation, whitespace

When importing files into the translation tool "MemoQ (8.4)" in the project manager role, I've found that trailing whitespace in the source data, is trimmed.

While this is re-added to the source when the file is exported; it is not added to the translated target. Instead, translators need to manually add the whitespace to the target; despite there being no indication that it's required.

Currently, most of the files I import are using the "Multilingual Delimited Filter" (that is, they are Excel and CSV files). However, if there is a filter which doesn't cause this issue - and no other way to solve the problem - I'm open to that.

**Is there any way I can import translatable data in MemoQ, without the whitespace being trimmed?**